# Nested loop Confusion

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

```
public class Exon303 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 109;

        do {
            for(int i = 3; i < 9; i = i * 2) {
                if(k % i ==3) {
                    k = k / 3;
                } else {
                    k = k / 2;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(k);
        } while(k > 0);
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                for(int m = 0; m < i * 2; m++) {
                    if(m == j && m == i) {
                        System.out.println("i: " + i);
                        System.out.println("j: " + j);
                        System.out.println("m: " + m);
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
    } 
}
```

Can someone explain to me the output of these loops I created I've hand traced it twice now and for some reason, I am getting a different output when I trace it.

```
Expected output:
27
6
1
0
i: 1
j: 1
m: 1
```

Here is my handtraced output below

```
Handtraced output:
54 
27
9
4
2
0
i: 0
j: 0
m: 0
i: 1 
j: 1
m: 1
```

Comment: can you provide the 2 outputs you're getting?

Comment: sure give me one sec.

Comment: What is your expected output and actual output?

Comment: You should add `i: 0`, `j: 0`, `m: 0` to your expected output as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You was wrong in tracing your code by hand. Let me explain.

Separate your code to 2 parts. 1st part:

```
    int k = 109;

    do {
        for(int i = 3; i < 9; i = i * 2) {
            if(k % i ==3) {
                k = k / 3;
            } else {
                k = k / 2;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(k);
    } while(k > 0);
```

You printed `k` outside of `for` loop, then `k / 2` twice each for loop (i = 3, 6), after 1st `while` loop, `k = (k / 2) / 2 = 27`. It is the same with next `while` loops when `k` does not have any value that make `k % i == 3`. So next values of k in each `while` loop is `27/4 = 6` and `6/4 = 1`. This is `k, i` values at beginning of each for loop:

```
---- while loop ----
k = 109, i = 3
k = 54, i = 6 => print k / 2 = 27
---- while loop ----
k = 27, i = 3 
k = 13, i = 6 => print k / 2 = 6
---- while loop ----
k = 6, i = 3 
k = 3, i = 6 => print k / 2 = 1
---- while loop ----
k = 1, i = 3 
k = 0, i = 6 => print k / 2 = 0
----> k == 0, break while loop
```

2nd part:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            for(int m = 0; m < i * 2; m++) {
                if(m == j && m == i) {
                    System.out.println("i: " + i);
                    System.out.println("j: " + j);
                    System.out.println("m: " + m);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The condition to print i, j, m values is `m == j == i` and `i, j` only have 2 values `0, 1`, but the condition `m < i*2` make `for` loop of `m` is ignored when `i = 0` and `m = 0`. So the only output: `i = j = m = 1`.

Comment: thanks totally got it